# Javascript - a problem with a two-step text input word conversion

Tags: javascript, html

Here I am making a word conversion tool which changes a certain word X into Y, or X to Y to Z by using javascript.

Progress: [HERE](https://jstrieb.github.io/urlpages/editor/#eyJjc3MiOiIiLCJqcyI6IiIsImh0bWwiOiI8IURPQ1RZUEUgaHRtbD5cbjxodG1sPlxuPGhlYWQ+XG4gICAgPHRpdGxlPlRpdGxlPC90aXRsZT5cbjxtZXRhIGNoYXJzZXQ9XCJ1dGYtOFwiPlxuPG1ldGEgbmFtZT1cInZpZXdwb3J0XCIgY29udGVudD1cIndpZHRoPWRldmljZS13aWR0aCwgaW5pdGlhbC1zY2FsZT0xLjBcIj5cblxuIDxzY3JpcHQgdHlwZT1cInRleHQvamF2YXNjcmlwdFwiPlxuXG52YXIgY29udmVyc2lvbiA9IHtcblwib25lXCI6XCJ0d29cIixcbn07XG5cbnZhciBjb252ZXJzaW9uMiA9IHtcblwidHdvXCI6XCJ0aHJlZVwiLFxufTtcblxuXG5cblxuIHZhciBtYXhMZW5ndGggPSBPYmplY3Qua2V5cyhjb252ZXJzaW9uKVxuICAgIC5yZWR1Y2UoKGEsIGIpID0+IGEubGVuZ3RoID4gYi5sZW5ndGggPyBhIDogYikgLy8gZ2V0IHRoZSBsb25nZXN0IHdvcmRcbiAgICAubGVuZ3RoOyAvLyBhbmQgaXQncyBsZW5ndGhcbiAgXG4gIGZ1bmN0aW9uIGNvbnZlcnQgKHRleHQpIHtcbiAgICB2YXIgY29udmVydGVkID0gXCJcIjtcbiAgICB2YXIgY3VyID0gMDtcbiAgICB3aGlsZSAoY3VyIDwgdGV4dC5sZW5ndGgpIHtcbiAgICAgIHZhciB0ZXN0ZWRQaG9uZW1lO1xuICAgICAgdmFyIHN5bWJvbCA9IHVuZGVmaW5lZDtcbiAgICAgIGZvciAodmFyIGxlbmd0aCA9IG1heExlbmd0aDsgbGVuZ3RoID4gMDsgbGVuZ3RoIC0tKSB7XG4gICAgICAgIHRlc3RlZFBob25lbWUgPSB0ZXh0LnN1YnN0cihjdXIsIGxlbmd0aCk7XG4gICAgICAgIGlmIChjb252ZXJzaW9uW3Rlc3RlZFBob25lbWVdKSB7XG4gICAgICAgICAgc3ltYm9sID0gY29udmVyc2lvblt0ZXN0ZWRQaG9uZW1lXTtcbiAgICAgICAgICBicmVhazsgLy8gc3RvcCB0aGUgbG9vcFxuICAgICAgICB9XG4gICAgICB9XG4gICAgICBpZiAoc3ltYm9sKSB7XG4gICAgICAgIGNvbnZlcnRlZCArPSBzeW1ib2w7XG4gICAgICAgIGN1ciArPSB0ZXN0ZWRQaG9uZW1lLmxlbmd0aDtcbiAgICAgIH1cbiAgICAgIGVsc2Uge1xuICAgICAgICBjb252ZXJ0ZWQgKz0gdGV4dFtjdXJdXG4gICAgICAgIGN1cisrO1xuICAgICAgfVxuICAgIH1cbiAgICByZXR1cm4gY29udmVydGVkXG4gIH1cblxuXG5cblxuIHZhciBtYXhMZW5ndGgyID0gT2JqZWN0LmtleXMoY29udmVyc2lvbjIpXG4gICAgLnJlZHVjZSgoYSwgYikgPT4gYS5sZW5ndGggPiBiLmxlbmd0aCA/IGEgOiBiKSAvLyBnZXQgdGhlIGxvbmdlc3Qgd29yZFxuICAgIC5sZW5ndGg7IC8vIGFuZCBpdCdzIGxlbmd0aFxuICBcbiAgZnVuY3Rpb24gY29udmVydDIgKHRleHQpIHtcbiAgICB2YXIgY29udmVydGVkMiA9IFwiXCI7XG4gICAgdmFyIGN1cjIgPSAwO1xuICAgIHdoaWxlIChjdXIyIDwgdGV4dC5sZW5ndGgpIHtcbiAgICAgIHZhciB0ZXN0ZWRQaG9uZW1lMjtcbiAgICAgIHZhciBzeW1ib2wyID0gdW5kZWZpbmVkO1xuICAgICAgZm9yICh2YXIgbGVuZ3RoID0gbWF4TGVuZ3RoMjsgbGVuZ3RoID4gMDsgbGVuZ3RoIC0tKSB7XG4gICAgICAgIHRlc3RlZFBob25lbWUyID0gdGV4dC5zdWJzdHIoY3VyMiwgbGVuZ3RoKTtcbiAgICAgICAgaWYgKGNvbnZlcnNpb24yW3Rlc3RlZFBob25lbWUyXSkge1xuICAgICAgICAgIHN5bWJvbDIgPSBjb252ZXJzaW9uMlt0ZXN0ZWRQaG9uZW1lMl07XG4gICAgICAgICAgYnJlYWs7IC8vIHN0b3AgdGhlIGxvb3BcbiAgICAgICAgfVxuICAgICAgfVxuICAgICAgaWYgKHN5bWJvbDIpIHtcbiAgICAgICAgY29udmVydGVkMiArPSBzeW1ib2wyO1xuICAgICAgICBjdXIyICs9IHRlc3RlZFBob25lbWUyLmxlbmd0aDtcbiAgICAgIH1cbiAgICAgIGVsc2Uge1xuICAgICAgICBjb252ZXJ0ZWQyICs9IHRleHRbY3VyMl1cbiAgICAgICAgY3VyMisrO1xuICAgICAgfVxuICAgIH1cbiAgICByZXR1cm4gY29udmVydGVkMlxuICB9XG5cblxuXG5cbiAgZnVuY3Rpb24gb25JbnB1dFRleHRDaGFuZ2UodHh0KSB7XG4gICAgdmFyIG91dHB1dFRleHRhcmVhRWxlbSA9IGRvY3VtZW50LmdldEVsZW1lbnRCeUlkKFwib3V0cHV0X3RleHRhcmVhXCIpO1xuICAgIHZhciBkaXYgPSBkb2N1bWVudC5jcmVhdGVFbGVtZW50KFwiZGl2XCIpO1xuICAgIHZhciBvdXRwdXRIdG1sRW50aXRpZXMgPSBjb252ZXJ0KHR4dCk7XG4gICAgZGl2LmlubmVySFRNTCA9IG91dHB1dEh0bWxFbnRpdGllcztcbiAgICBvdXRwdXRUZXh0YXJlYUVsZW0udmFsdWUgPSBkaXYuaW5uZXJUZXh0O1xuICB9XG5cbiAgZnVuY3Rpb24gb25PdXRwdXRUZXh0Q2hhbmdlKHR4dCkge1xuICAgIHZhciBvdXRwdXRUZXh0YXJlYUVsZW0yID0gZG9jdW1lbnQuZ2V0RWxlbWVudEJ5SWQoXCJvdXRwdXRfdGV4dGFyZWEyXCIpO1xuICAgIHZhciBkaXYgPSBkb2N1bWVudC5jcmVhdGVFbGVtZW50KFwiZGl2XCIpO1xuICAgIHZhciBvdXRwdXRIdG1sRW50aXRpZXMyID0gY29udmVydDIodHh0KTtcbiAgICBkaXYuaW5uZXJIVE1MID0gb3V0cHV0SHRtbEVudGl0aWVzMjtcbiAgICBvdXRwdXRUZXh0YXJlYUVsZW0yLnZhbHVlID0gZGl2LmlubmVyVGV4dDtcbiAgfVxuICBcblxuIDwvc2NyaXB0PlxuICAgIFxuXG5cbjwvaGVhZD5cbjxib2R5PiAgICBcblxuPGNlbnRlcj48aDEgY2xhc3M9XCJ0ZXh0LWNlbnRlclwiPlR3by1zdGVwIGZ1bmN0aW9uIC0gd29yZCBjb252ZXJ0ZXI8L2gxPlxuPHA+UHJvdG90eXBlIDI6IElucHV0ID4gT3V0cHV0ID4gT3V0cHV0Mi48YnI+b25lID4gdHdvLCB0d28gPiB0aHJlZTwvY2VudGVyPjxicj5cblxuPGNlbnRlcj5cblxuPHRleHRhcmVhXG5pZD1cImlucHV0X3RleHRhcmVhXCJcbmF1dG9mb2N1cz1cIlwiXG5wbGFjZWhvbGRlcj1cIlN0ZXAgMS4gSW5wdXQgKHR5cGUgb25lISlcIlxucm93cz1cIjEwXCJcbm9uaW5wdXQ9XCJvbklucHV0VGV4dENoYW5nZSh0aGlzLnZhbHVlKVwiIHN0eWxlPVwid2lkdGg6MzAwcHhcIj48L3RleHRhcmVhPiAgICBcblxuPHRleHRhcmVhIFxucm93cz1cIjEwXCJcbnBsYWNlaG9sZGVyPVwiU3RlcCAyLiBPdXRwdXQgKHR5cGUgdHdvISlcIiBcbmlkPVwib3V0cHV0X3RleHRhcmVhXCJcbm9uaW5wdXQ9XCJvbk91dHB1dFRleHRDaGFuZ2UodGhpcy52YWx1ZSlcIiBzdHlsZT1cIndpZHRoOjMwMHB4XCI+PC90ZXh0YXJlYT4gICAgXG5cbjx0ZXh0YXJlYSBcbnJvd3M9XCIxMFwiIFxucGxhY2Vob2xkZXI9XCJTdGVwIDMuIE91dHB1dDJcIiBcbmlkPVwib3V0cHV0X3RleHRhcmVhMlwiIFxuc3R5bGU9XCJ3aWR0aDozMDBweFwiPjwvdGV4dGFyZWE+XG48L2NlbnRlcj5cblx0XG5cblxuPC9ib2R5PlxuPC9odG1sPiJ9)

Here is the entire javascript:

```
var conversion = {
"one":"two",
};
var conversion2 = {
"two":"three",
};

 var maxLength = Object.keys(conversion)
    .reduce((a, b) => a.length > b.length ? a : b) 
    .length;

  function convert (text) {
    var converted = "";
    var cur = 0;
    while (cur < text.length) {
      var testedPhoneme;
      var symbol = undefined;
      for (var length = maxLength; length > 0; length --) {
        testedPhoneme = text.substr(cur, length);
        if (conversion[testedPhoneme]) {
          symbol = conversion[testedPhoneme];
          break; // stop the loop
        }
      }
      if (symbol) {
        converted += symbol;
        cur += testedPhoneme.length;
      }
      else {
        converted += text[cur]
        cur++;
      }
    }
    return converted
  }


 var maxLength2 = Object.keys(conversion2)
    .reduce((a, b) => a.length > b.length ? a : b) 
    .length; 
  
  function convert2 (text) {
    var converted2 = "";
    var cur2 = 0;
    while (cur2 < text.length) {
      var testedPhoneme2;
      var symbol2 = undefined;
      for (var length = maxLength2; length > 0; length --) {
        testedPhoneme2 = text.substr(cur2, length);
        if (conversion2[testedPhoneme2]) {
          symbol2 = conversion2[testedPhoneme2];
          break; // stop the loop
        }
      }
      if (symbol2) {
        converted2 += symbol2;
        cur2 += testedPhoneme2.length;
      }
      else {
        converted2 += text[cur2]
        cur2++;
      }
    }
    return converted2
  }

  function onInputTextChange(txt) {
    var outputTextareaElem = document.getElementById("output_textarea");
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    var outputHtmlEntities = convert(txt);
    div.innerHTML = outputHtmlEntities;
    outputTextareaElem.value = div.innerText;
  }

  function onOutputTextChange(txt) {
    var outputTextareaElem2 = document.getElementById("output_textarea2");
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    var outputHtmlEntities2 = convert2(txt);
    div.innerHTML = outputHtmlEntities2;
    outputTextareaElem2.value = div.innerText;
  }
```

In the page that I made so far, there are three `<textarea>`s; **Input**, **Output** and **Output2**.

Currently, thanks to this piece of code;

```
var conversion = {
"one":"two",
};
var conversion2 = {
"two":"three",
};
```

If *one* is typed into **Input**, **Output** renders *two*. If *two* is ***manually*** typed into **Output**, *three* gets rendered in **Output2**.

Here is the problem, I want to render *three* in **Output2** only through typing *one* into **Input**, but a direct two-step conversion seems unavailable yet. In other words, **Input** > **Output** (*one* > *two*) and **Output** > **Output2** (*two* > *three*) conversion is available, but **Input** > **Output** > **Output2** (*one* > *two* > *three*) is unavailable.

What needs to be done to solve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: hello, still the "u ku tsu" translator ? i'll look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, not exactly what you asked, but I could do something that works

Here is the example : https://jsfiddle.net/alias_gui3/8knw57u0/94/

### how to use it :

#### to add new characters OR new languages/scripts

just complete the dictionnary :

```js
var dictionnary = [
  {
    latin: "u",
    japanese: "う",
    emoji: ""
    // add any script for every characters
  },{
    latin: "ku",
    japanese: "く",
    emoji: ""
  },{
    latin: "tsu",
    japanese: "つ",
    emoji: ""
  }
  // add any character with the same format
]
```

#### to add new textareas :

give your textarea a recognizable id (eg. id="cyrillic")
then connect your textarea with this method:

```js
// connect your textareas below !!
addTextArea(
  document.querySelector("#latin"), 
  "latin"
);
addTextArea(
  document.querySelector("#japanese"), 
  "japanese"
);
addTextArea(
  document.querySelector("#emoji"), 
  "emoji"
);
// add new textarea with a new language here
```

then all the connections are done, you can edit all your textareas, if they recognise a character they will translate it in all the other textareas

---

### full code

```js
var dictionnary = [
  {
    latin: "u",
    japanese: "う",
    emoji: ""
    // add any script for every characters
  },{
    latin: "ku",
    japanese: "く",
    emoji: ""
  },{
    latin: "tsu",
    japanese: "つ",
    emoji: ""
  }
  // add any character with the same format
]
// calculate the max length for each language :
var max = {}
dictionnary.forEach(
  char => {
    Object.keys(char).forEach(script => {
      max[script] = max[script]
        ? char[script].length > max[script]
          ? char[script].length
          : max[script]
        : char[script].length
    })
  }
)// now max contains the maximum length of sequence
// for each language

function findSymbol (
  originSymbol,
  originScript,
  destinationScript
) {
  for (var i = 0; i < dictionnary.length; i++) {
    var char = dictionnary[i];
    if (char[originScript] === originSymbol) {
      return char[destinationScript]
    }
  }
  return false // if not found
}



function translate (
  text, 
  originScript, 
  destinationScript
 ) {
   var cur = 0;
   var translated = "";
   var maxLength = max[originScript]
   while (cur < text.length) {
    var testedPhoneme;
    var symbol = false;
    for (var length=maxLength; length > 0; length--) {
      testedPhoneme = text.substr(cur, length);
      symbol = findSymbol(
        testedPhoneme, 
        originScript,
        destinationScript
      )
      if (symbol) {
        break; // stop the loop
      }
    }
    if (symbol) {
      translated += symbol;
      cur += testedPhoneme.length;
    }
    else {
      translated += text[cur];
      cur++;
    }
  }
  return translated
}

var textareas = []; // the list of your textareas

function addTextArea(element, originScript) {
  textareas.push({
    element: element,
    script: originScript
  })
  element.addEventListener("input", function (e) {
    signalTextChanged(element, originScript)
  });
}

function signalTextChanged (
  originElement, 
  originScript
) {
  var originText = originElement.value;
  textareas.forEach(function (textarea) {
    if (textarea.element !== originElement) {
      var translated = translate(
        originText,
        originScript,
        textarea.script
      )
      textarea.element.value = translated;
    }
  })
}

// connect your textareas below !!
addTextArea(
  document.querySelector("#latin"), 
  "latin"
);
addTextArea(
  document.querySelector("#japanese"), 
  "japanese"
);
addTextArea(
  document.querySelector("#emoji"), 
  "emoji"
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>

  </head>
  <body>  
    <center>

      <h1>Latin to foreign script converter 3</h1>
      <p>type in u, ku, tsu in the FIRST panel</p>

      <textarea
                id="latin"
                autofocus=""
                placeholder="type text in latin ! (u ku or tsu)"
                rows="10" 
                style="width:300px"></textarea>    

      <textarea  
                id="japanese"
                rows="10"
                placeholder="type text in japanese !"
                style="width:300px"></textarea>    

      <textarea 
                id="emoji"
                rows="10" 
                placeholder="type text in emojis !!"
                style="width:300px"></textarea>
    </center>



    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes, it is working fine! I'm not sure why, but the html and javascript that I copied from your answer does not seem to work, although it works well in the code snippet and jsfiiddle. I coppied the js part and pasted it into the <script> element. Could you tell my why?

Comment: what do you get in the console ? try calling `translate('ukutsu','latin','japanese')` to see if it's working

Comment: Your answer is helpful as I find it inspiring, but actually it looks like I still have a problem.  I intend to make conversion 1>2 and 2>3 disconnected, and the only connection is the output text displayed on the second panel. https://jsfiddle.net/victorlee/u5jpc2ef/2/ Here I made two conversion words for 1>2 and one word for 2>3. If I type **12** into the left panel, the right panel does not directly render **success**, unless I press space bar or some other keys on the center panel, which is my major problem. Any suggestions about this one? Thanks.

Comment: yes, the problem is you only trigger the conversion2 when typing manually in textarea2, you can solve your problem by calling the 2 functions when typing in textarea1

Comment: sorry, i just tested it and it doesn't work, you need to do something more complicated ... looking for it

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/alias_gui3/09snyqj8/11/ now it works, you need to make a few changes where i commented

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I fully understand what you're trying to achieve here

There are some duplications in your code, what if you'll have 10 fields for output, will you create a special function for each of them?

Try to simplify things.

One way would be to loop through all of your lists as follows:

1. Put all your conversation in a list

   ```
   var lists = [conversion, conversion2];
   ```
2. Add `isInNextList` function to check if your text is a key in the next list

   ```
   function isInNextList(index, key) {
        if (lists.length < index) {
            return false;
        }
        return Object.keys(lists[index]).includes(key);
    }
   ```
3. change your `onInputTextChange` function as follow:

   ```
    function onInputTextChange(txt) {
        var index = 0;
        var text = txt;
        while (isInNextList(index, text)) {
            var outputTextareaElem = document.getElementById(
                'output_textarea_' + index
            );
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            text = lists[index][text]; //next key
            index++;
            div.innerHTML = text;
            outputTextareaElem.value = div.innerText;
        }
    }
   ```
4. change your output textarea's ids to contain the index

   ```
            id="output_textarea_0"
            id="output_textarea_1"
   ```

There are other improvements that can be made like:
Creating the output fields dynamically,
Clear output fields  etc.